# Prisma Docker cannot connect MySQL 8 "Connection is not available" "Connection refused (Connection refused)"

Tags: mysql, docker, prisma

I’m setting up local development using Prisma with Docker and MySQL. I have problem setting up the environment with MySQL version 8. Below is my `docker-compose` file

```
version: ‘3.7’
services:
prisma:
image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.19
restart: always
ports:
- “4466:4466”
depends_on:
- mysql
environment:
PRISMA_CONFIG: |
port: 4466
# uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
# managementApiSecret: my-secret
databases:
default:
connector: mysql
host: mysql
port: 3306
user: root
password: prisma
migrations: true
mysql:
image: mysql
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
restart: always
ports:
- “3306:3306”
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
volumes:
- mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
mysql:
```

But Prisma seem cannot connect to the MySQL database. Below is the error (Setup is working fine with MySQL 5.7 and PostgresSQL):

```
Exception in thread “main” java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: database - Connection is not available, request timed out after 5002ms.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:14)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.(JdbcBackend.scala:453)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:46)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:249)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession$(BasicBackend.scala:248)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=mysql)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:161)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:79)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1040)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:490)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:144)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:90)
at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.scala:101)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:193)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:430)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:64)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:570)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:563)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
… 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:398)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1032)
… 14 more
```

Any idea know how to fix the error regarding connection to MySQL version 8?

Comment: Try starting MySQL 8.0 in native password mode see if that helps  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html

Comment: Hi thanks for yrs response. Any detail how to change docker-compose file? or any other secure way?

Comment: not possible  native password mode needs to be configured in mysql on commandline or in the mysql config..

Comment: can we add some command to the startup of the image? maybe additional build step?